# converting a for cycle in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, apply, cycle

I would like to convert a for cycle into a faster operation such as apply.

Here is my code

```
for(a in 1:dim(k)[1]){

for(b in 1:dim(k)[2]){

if( (k[a,b,1,1]==0) & (k[a,b,1,2]==0) & (k[a,b,1,3]==0) ){

  k[a,b,1,1]<-1

  k[a,b,1,2]<-1

  k[a,b,1,3]<-1

      }
        }
          }
```

It's a simple code that does a check on each element of the multidimensional array k and if the three elements are the same and equal to 0, it assigns the value 1.

Is there a way to make it faster?. The matrix k has 1,444,000 elements and it takes too long to run it. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a *reproducible* example.

Comment: my k matrix is really big, but just imagine it could be defined as follows `k<-array(c(1,1,1,0,2,2,2,0,3,3,3,0),dim=c(2,2,3))`

Comment: Just paste `dput(head(k))` or, if this is still too big, narrow down the dimensions to include `k[c(1,2), c(1,2), 1, c(1:3)]`.

Comment: `>k[c(1,2), c(1,2), 1, c(1:3)]

, , 1


     [,1] [,2]

[1,]    0    0

[2,]    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]

[1,]    0    0

[2,]    0    0

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]

[1,]    0    0

[2,]    0    0`

and also

` cimg [1:800, 1:600, 1, 1:3] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...`

Comment: How about you accept answers to your previous questions before asking new ones.

Answer (score 2):

With apply you can return all your 3-combinations as a numeric vector and then check for your specific condition:

```
    # This creates an array with the same properties as yours
    array <- array(data = sample(c(0, 1), 81, replace = TRUE, 
                         prob = c(0.9, 0.1)), c(3, 3, 3, 3))

    # This loops over all vectors in the fourth dimension and returns a
    # vector of ones if your condition is met
    apply(array, MARGIN = c(1, 2, 3), FUN = function(x) {
      if (sum(x) == 0 & length(unique(x)) == 1)
        return(c(1, 1, 1))
      else
        return(x)
    })
```

Note that the `MARGIN` argument specifies the dimensions over which to loop. You want the fourth dimension vectors so you specify `c(1, 2, 3)`.

If you then assign this newly created array to the old one, you replaced all vectors where the condition is met with ones.

Comment: Note that `sum(x) == 0` might be `TRUE` if `x` contains both negative and positive values,

Comment: Yeah I just added `length(unique(x)) == 1`. Thanks.

Comment: Did the posted solution work? If it did, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should first use the filter function twice (composed), and then the apply (lapply?) function on the filtered array. Maybe you can also reduce the array, because it looks like you're not very interested in the third dimension (always accessing the 1st item). You should probably do some reading about functional programming in R here http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html

**Note** I'm not a R programmer, but I'm quite familiar with functional programming (Haskell etc) so this might give you an idea. This might be faster, but it depends a bit on how R is designed (lazy or eager evaluation etc).